# Database Design: Primary key and many to many associations

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-keys, primary-key

This is my first database design of my home library. I have a question about how to implement the primary keys in each table, I am also interested to know if it is acceptable to have many tables associated with one foreign as I have with the many relationships with "contributor_id."

[image: Link to image of design]

Not all of my tables have a primary key. If a primary key should NOT be the foreign key (as I have come to understand it) what could serve as a primary key in copy_info and book_info tables? I am not sure I have correctly implemented the intermediary tables where there many to many relationships might exist. Is this a situation where I should require a composite primary 
key?

Maybe there are differing opinions on how to do this, but any insight would be appreciated. Where I am brand new to this, please excuse if my question is not sufficiently specific.

Comment: [_Tips on optimal many-to-many table design_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table)

Comment: You need to read a college/university intro to database design. Then follow a design method from it. Then ask one specific question in that context. The main thing wrong here is you need to drop contributer_id and introduce Edits(book_id, contributer_id), Illustrates(...), etc. But the justification is a couple of chapters of the textbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was misunderstanding how to implement a many-to-many relationship. Once I put in junction tables, my tables all had primary keys.
[Updated Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lMtg.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I just give few quick advices:

- I understand the 4 tables on the left are intermediary tables between book_info and other 4 tables with translators info, authors info and so on; am I right? So is a many-to-many relationships (a book can have many authors and one authors has many books), but if you set up the tables like this every time you try to insert **the same contributor for another book** it will cause a duplicate key error! So, **remove the keys** from there.
- the right way to assign a key to these aggregate tables with be to assign the key to both values (so you will never break the "uniqueness" constraint), **BUT** is completely unuseful (and a waste of space and Db resources) to assign keys in these simple aggregate tables
- *books and book_info is a one-to-one relationship?* So it makes sense to split this in 2 separate tables ONLY for tidiness purposes (for example if you have a lot of fields and you want to separate them by some logical criteria)

  books and book_info is another many-to-many relationship? In this case the "id" field as key is a correct solution, but is not correct to couple together the tables books and copy_info (better to couple the copy_info to the book_info, so you wil split it to two one-to-many relationship (easier to manage in this case)

i hope I helped a little, anyway you can easily solve it with little practice on the field.

Comment: the way this is currently set up, I cannot have one contributor connected to multiple books because of duplicity error. If I understand you correctly, if these 4 tables do not have keys at all, I don't have to worry about uniqueness. I don't fully understand your last point, is it that because book_info is a one to many relationship to copy_info (i can own multiple copies of one book) so it doesn't need the intermediary table of books? EDIT: [like this?](http://imgur.com/a/loXSg)

Comment: Better! One to many never needs the intermediary table. You got my point. About copy_info, you plan to own multiple copies of one book, but how you will distinguish between them? If they have same publisher, same pub_date, and so on? They can have different conditions, but in this case your tables is too complicate for no good reason.

Comment: I have since added a primary key to the copy_info table called copy_id, I also moved publisher to the copy_info table. In some instances I might have multiple copies of the same book but with different publish dates(editions) or in different languages so having a one-to-many relationship between book_info and copy_info makes sense to me. You're tips have been illuminating, thank you kindly.